# Jquery External Page Smooth Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay here is the problem i am currently facing how can i get jquery to smooth scroll to an anchor link when the anchor link has a name or a id.

```
<a name="scrollhere"> Smooth Scroll here on page load </a>
<a id="scrollhere"> Smooth Scroll here on page load </a>
```

so regardless of what the anchor link says it should smooth scroll once the page is loaded.
Here is the code a guy gave me it works. But the only problem is this code only works if this is the secnario

```
<a class="scrollhere"> Smooth Scroll here on page load </a>
```

the code only works if the anchor link has a class of where i want the smooth scroll to go. But i want it to be a name and or a id.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
       var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
       $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.'+urlHash).offset().top}, 4000);  
});
```

tell me how i can alter this code to do what i want it to do

Answer (score 1):

You can search for each of the areas you'd like to match on and return the first match, like this:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.'+urlHash+', #'+urlHash+', [name='+urlHash+']').first().offset().top}, 4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To look for an `id`:

```
scrollTop:$('#'+urlHash);
```

To look for a name:

```
scrollTop:$('[name='+urlHash+']');
```